# useEffect: dependency array fails to prevent infinite rerender

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a useEffect with a dependency array below and can't understand why it continues to re-render regardless. The logic is simple to get `tuition` data, then add it to a `program` object in the `programData` array. Can someone explain to me why a rerender loop is created here?

This is a Next.js app. `getData` updates `props.tableData`, passed from a redux store. `tableData` is a slow-to-change value.

```
function ProgramsTable(props) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const locationId = router.query.id;
  const { tableData } = props;
  let programData = tableData;

  let tuitions = useSelector(state => state.tables.tuitions);

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();

    (async function() {
      if (Boolean(tuitions) === false) {
        tuitions = await getTuitionsByLocationId(locationId);
      }
    })();
    console.log(`tuitions`, tuitions);
    console.log(`tableData`, tableData); // both print continuously

    // merge tuition data onto matching program data
    programData = Array.from(programData).map(program => {
      const programId = program?.id;

      const tuitionsIsDefined = tuitions && Array.from(tuitions).length > 0;

      tuitionsIsDefined && tuitions.forEach(tuition => {
        const tuitionProgramId = tuition?.program?.id;

        if (tuitionProgramId === programId) {
          if (Array.isArray(program.tuitions) === false) {
            program.tuitions = [];
          }

          program.tuitions.push(tuition);
        }
      });

      return program;
    });

    console.log('edited programData', programData); // also prints continuously
  }, [tuitions, programData, tableData]);
```

Comment: What type is `props.tableData`?

Comment: getData changes props.tableData. tableData is in the dependency array, so the effect reruns. Rerunning calls getData, restarting the loop. As for how to fix this... when do you want the effect to run? Just when the component mounts?

Comment: @arminfro it is an object array

Comment: Maybe this can helps https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14476#issuecomment-471199055? I suppose that it re-renders because you pass an array to dependency array

Comment: Yeah, you need to save the reference, by using `useMemo`. Dependecies are always tricky if it's a reference type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be rerendered continuously. And it works well. The reason is the following.

1. `tuitions`, `programData`, `tableData` all these dependencies change inside `useEffect` callback.

```
programData = Array.from(programData).map(...
//Creates a completely new programData.
```

2. That's why it creates an infinite loop. It's enough to create infinite loop with one of these dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Question is bit unclear where data is changing and why you are subscribe those 3 objects at a time and there no flag in between`getTuitionsByLocationId`, You have to put a flag in useEffect `[tuitions, programData, tableData]` among these 3 anyone of them getting updated somewhere in your code and re-rendering everything.